# Reduce mantissa bit-width

Tags: floating-point, neural-network, fixed-point, exponent, mantissa

*Well, I feel embarrassed I cannot get this by my own, but..*
**How can I reduce the mantissa** (and exponent) **bit-with for a floating point number?**

---

I am training a (convolutional) artificial neural network (and I'm implementing it on FPGA) and I'd like to study the relation between mantissa (and exponent) bit-width vs. testing (and training) accuracy on CPU (and GPU). Next step would be converting my floats into a fixed point representation (that is what I am using on FPGA) and see how stuff goes.

Similar kind of studies have been already done by others ([Tong, Rutenbar and Nagle (1998)] and [Leeser and Zhao (2003)]), so there should be a way of doing this, although the 'how' is not yet clear to me.

Last point, I'm programming in Lua, but I can easily include C stuff with `ffi` of LuaJIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove *s* bits from the significand of a binary floating-point number *x* and round the remaining bits, use Veltkamp’s algorithm:

```
Let factor = 2**s + 1.
Let c = factor * x.
Let y = c - (c-x).
```

Each operation above should be computed with floating-point arithmetic, including rounding-to-nearest with the same precision as *x*. Then *y* is the desired result.

Note that this will round a single number to a shorter significand. It will not generally reproduce the results of computing with shorter significands. E.g., given *a* and *b*, computing *a*•*b* with greater precision and then rounding to lesser precision will not always have the same result as computing *a*•*b* with the final precision.

To decrease the exponent range, you can merely compare a value to thresholds for the new exponent range and declare underflow or overflow as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much. This will be good to take in consideration in the future, since now I've just to truncate my float at a specific bit after the point (number:mul(2^b):floor():div(2^b)) since we are still using static fixed point numbers. Next year we might switch to dynamic fixed point, and then I will be tackling the mantissa :)